# Ошибка с ReactDOM.render()

Tags: reactjs

Делая простое приложение, при запуске выдает ошибку `Target container is not a DOM element.` В чем моя проблема?

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import App from "./App";
import * as serviceWorker from "./serviceWorker";

ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
serviceWorker.unregister();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

К моменту выполнения скрипта элемент документа еще не доступен, поскольку сам скрипт видимо находится в заголовке.

Метод [**`document.getElementById`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) возвращает ссылку на элемент по его идентификатору (`ID`) или `null`, если элемент с указанным `ID` не найден в документе. Видимо вторым параметром в `ReactDOM.render` приходит `null`.

Лучше поместить ваш скрипт в самый конец тела HTML документа и отобразить корневой компонент `root` в `div` перед тем, как будет объявлен сценарий следующим образом:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="root"></div>
  <script src="/bundle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Также советую разместить `BrowserRouter` внутри вашего компонента `App` - э то будет правильнее, и выглядеть будет проще:

```
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Моя ошибка это. В файле `public/index.html` была разметка:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- ... tags above the title stay untouched ... -->
    <title>App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://bootswatch.com/4/flatly/bootstrap.min.css">
  </head>
  <!-- ... body definition stays untouched ... -->
</html>
```

Добавил `body` и все заработало:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- ... tags above the title stay untouched ... -->
    <title>App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://bootswatch.com/4/flatly/bootstrap.min.css">
  </head>
  <!-- ... body definition stays untouched ... -->
  <body>
    <noscript>
      You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.
    </noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Наиболее универсальное решение, это использование [события load](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/load).

Основное преимущество этого подхода в том, что данный код будет гарантированно выполнен после полной загрузки DOM, вне зависимости от того где вы разместили тег `<script>`.

Так же следует иметь ввиду, что в случае размещения `<script>` в конце `<body>` поведение будет немного иным. Например, могут быть не загружены картинки или веб-компоненты не инициализированы.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import App from "./App";
import * as serviceWorker from "./serviceWorker";

window.addEventListener("load", () => {
    ReactDOM.render(
      <BrowserRouter>
        <App />
      </BrowserRouter>,
      document.getElementById("root")
    );
    serviceWorker.unregister();
});
```